# Microsoft Presidio support for spark using scala

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, presidio

Is there a way to use Microsoft Presidio for pii data encryption in Scala Spark? Is it only possible using pySpark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, looks like Microsoft Presidio support only Python. I came to this conclusion after seeing this [official documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/presidio/samples/), where only Python Sample code is given, also not able to find anything which indicates use of Scala.

[image]

But, you can raise feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/presidio/discussions/categories/requested-features)